# Request timed out with php + cURL

Tags: php, curl

What happens is that I have a script in php where it makes many requests to a website and my script is on my server. However, the problem is as follows:

[ERROR - REQUEST TIMED OUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27t2P.png)

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
$contador = 0;
$ran = explode("\n", file_get_contents('nombres.txt'));
$randomElement = $ran[array_rand($ran, 1)];

if ($file = fopen("correos.txt", "r")) {
    while(!feof($file)) {
        $line = fgets($file);


$var_post_data = 'site_id=1&email='.$line.'&name='.$randomElement.'id=39494393';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"site");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$var_post_data);  //Post Fields
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = [
    'Cookie: ws_visit_id=2_170927230320231_5878; has_track_visit=true; _uetsid=_uet0639d46c',
    'DNT: 1',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Cache-Control: no-cache',
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Host: site',
    'Referer: site', 
    'User-Agent: ' . $randomElement,
    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
echo curl_errno($ch); 
echo curl_error($ch);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

    echo $server_output ;
    echo $contador;
    $fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a');
    fwrite($fp, $server_output);
    $stringData = "-------------" . "\n";
    fwrite($fp, $stringData);

     // sleep for 240 sec
    #sleep(240); // sleep for 240 sec
    #sleep(240); // sleep for 240 sec
    #sleep(240); // sleep for 240 sec
if(curl_errno($ch) == 26) {
     sleep(30);
}
else {
     echo 'Not errors';
    continue;
}


   }
    fclose($file);
}
curl_close ($ch);



?>
```

I also clarified that I already configured the "max_execution_time" function on my server and set it to "0". I would appreciate if you could help me, I want the script to do it, and if the remote server gives that error, let my script do a sleep (). I have tried in all ways and it does not work for me.

Thank you!

Comment: `$line = fgets($file);` with every iteration this var is overwritten, effectively containing only the last line? Otherwise I don't see anything out of the ordinary with your script that would lead to timeout errors from your client point of view, are you in control of the server you post to?

Comment: How can i fix this from overwriting? so i try and come back here... And not, i'm not have control of remote server

Comment: @Scuzzy And thanks for you..

Answer (score 0):

you have several issues, 1: `$ran = explode("\n", file_get_contents('nombres.txt'));` here you use the linux-style newline \n as a delimiter, which would be ok except, `if ($file = fopen("correos.txt", "r")) {` here you open it in OS-native text mode, meaning newlines will be read with \r\n on some OSs (like Windows), \n on some (like Linux), and \r on some OSs (like older Mac's), thus this line only works on some OSs. to make it platform independent, open it in binary mode, "rb". next: `$var_post_data = 'site_id=1&email='.$line.'&name='.$randomElement.'id=39494393';`  here $line and $randomElement is not urlencoded, so if they contain & or = or ÆØÅ or lots of other characters, the encoding will be malformed, and the server is likely to respond with `400 Bad Request` or otherwise read corrupted data. use urlencode() to properly urlencode it. next: this code looks suspicious: `Cookie: ws_visit_id=2_170927230320231_5878`, are you sure you want to hardcode the cookie id, instead of just getting a fresh one? that cookie id probably expired long ago.. next: `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` this header is invalid, x-www-urlencoded does not support UTF8, it's always in ASCII encoding, with special encoding for non-ascii characters, but don't add this header at all, libcurl will add it for you, and unlike you, libcurl won't make any typos when doing so. 
but none of these problems explains your error message in the screenshot. looks like there's a load balancing scheme in your http server that kicks in for some reason, its a web server configuration problem, not a php problem. the error is probably generated by Apache or Nginx or IIS or whatever is in front of php.